# How to adjust the point at which skeleton css shifts it's boxes?

Tags: skeleton-css-boilerplate

I have a site built using the responsive Skeleton CSS framework (http://getskeleton.com) but when viewing on a phone in portrait mode, three columns across is automatically adjusted so the boxes are vertically stacked rather than all on one line. This has been fine in general but in one particular instance when the boxes have very little content, I need them to stay horizontal - all in one row/on one line. I cannot see anywhere in the css file where this is adjustable though?!

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a way if you're only applying SkeletonCSS classes directly to elements. Other utility class frameworks like [TachyonsCSS](http://tachyons.io/docs/layout/grid/) provide ways of controlling styles at different breakpoints. If you're trying to add styles specifically based on device orientation, you'll need to write a custom media query.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going old school and creating one twelve column row and putting the column divs inside a td tag each. I then applied some conditional padding at the different breakpoints. Sometimes, very occasionally, you still can't beat a table in my humble opinion!